# How to update JAVA_HOME for the entire system, not just my terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables, java-home

When I swap my JAVA_HOME to point to another env and close terminal and open it back up, I can echo it and it shows the right path.

However some other applications (name IntelliJ IDEA) will hold the first JAVA_HOME until I log my user out. Simply quitting IntelliJ IDEA like terminal doesn't work.

Why is this? I'm curious where does someone like IntelliJ actually get my JAVA_HOME in case I have one set in my bash_profile and my config_fish for instance. How does intellij (and other programs) know where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure about IntelliJ but in eclipse, you can set your environment in Window > preference > java > Installed JRE and add your path their

Comment: The thing is that intellij already has my JAVA_HOME, but if I change it in my bash_profile or config.fish it doesn't seem to take effect in intellij until I restart my computer. How does intellij know where to look upon system startup to get the right variable?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are such things as system env variables but in this case intellij wasn't pulling these from my system. Intellij instead knows how to look for your bash_profile among other configs (also zsh config and fish config)

See the source here: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/terminal/resources/jediterm-bash.in